# How far down the OSI model does one have to go to reduce latency in wireless protocols

Tags: wireless, latency, peripheral

I'm curious about protocols used for low latency peripheral devices. The famous examples would be [Logitech's lightspeed](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Logitech_Lightspeed#:%7E:text=Logitech%20Lightspeed%20is%20a%20wireless,a%20USB%20type%20A%20port.), [Razer's hyperspeed](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Razer_Hyperspeed) and [Corsair's Slipstream](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Corsair_Slipstream). The main selling point of which is that they can reduce the wireless latency to levels where the bottleneck starts to be the USB interface i.e. ~1 ms.

When implementing such proprietary protocols, with aims of pre-emptive retransmission and shifting between frequencies based on congestion etc. do we usually mean protocol stacks in the network layer and up? Or is it necessary to also implement new link layer protocols to make decisions about sacrificing e.g. security for better latency? Are there any examples of open technical standards which aim to achieve such an effect?

I couldn't find any whitepapers or talks on the topic, but if they exists that would be very helpful.

Comment: If you aren't swamped in a competitive environment where product maturity cycles are measured in months, then you analyze each situation and develop an appropriately designed system. That's how pros do it. Anything else? Then their products would not successfully compete. I'd love it if my competitors imagined there was a one-size-fits-all, bright line white paper solution to all problems they faced and then applied it without thinking much. That would make my job really easy and they'd never survive long.

Comment: If you are stuck in a situation where product life cycles are short and there's no time for all that stuff, then you take what you are given to use and apply it and tinker to optimize with what time you do have. I don't take those jobs as a consultant, though. That's my two cents worth.